# Selenium: Page gets refreshed after login

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

After the code clicks the action to login, the page gets refreshed and doesn't redirect to the next page. This only occurs for this website as I am redirected properly on other sites.
When I am giving the wrong credentials even the error message is not getting displayed.(Manually it works)

I am testing in Chrome with Selenium java.

Here is my code:

```
public class Test {

    private static final String HTMLPageSourceCode = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException   
    {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium project\\chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.manage().window().maximize();

       driver.get("https://-----/tandem/login");

       Thread.sleep(5000);

       driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

       driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("----");
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  

       driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("----");

       WebElement loginbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-button']"));
       Actions actions = new Actions(driver);  
       actions.click(loginbutton).perform();

   }

}
```

Comment: could You provide the link to the webpage You're trying to conduct login on?

Comment: Are You sure You did find all locators: xpath elements correctly?

Comment: Why do you need to use action class where you can only use `loginbutton.click()`

Comment: In addition to KunduK's comment, if you're going to use implicit wait you should use it before accessing any web elements (just once).  Also, since you're using sleep after page load, why aren't you also using sleep after your attempted actions click?  How are you even seeing a screen refresh since the click is the last statement?

Comment: https://outhouse.inhouseusa.com/tandem/login/? is the link.

Comment: I tried all the locators

Comment: I used action class as i was trying many possibilities and this worked for me.

Comment: What i understood is that the screen is refreshing as the session is not lasting for some time.Thank you for the quick replay guys.

Answer (score 1):

To login in into the website `https://outhouse.inhouseusa.com/tandem/login/` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  //options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://outhouse.inhouseusa.com/tandem/login/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.form-control#login"))).sendKeys("sandy");
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-control#password")).sendKeys("sandy");
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.pull-right.button.button-primary#login-button")).click();
  ```

Comment: Then most likely your user name or password is incorrect.

Comment: @BillHileman Yes, I tried with a set of incorrect credentials. But I didn't find anything suspicious.

Comment: @BillHileman Yes, I tried with a set of incorrect credentials. But I didn't find anything suspicious.

Comment: @sandy Can you share with us a working set of credentials please?

Comment: If the credentials was incorrect ,are you getting this message "Error: The information you entered is incorrect"??

Comment: I am not getting that either

Comment: @sandy Manually do you get that message? Can you update the question with all these information please?

Comment: @DebanjanB:It was the issue with the application.Google recaptcha was blocking the login.